# how to update a textview with system's time in am pm

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` which is intended to show phone's time and it should be updated every minute according to the changing minutes of phone's time.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Intent `ACTION_TIME_TICK` sent by the system every minutes.

First you have to implement a broadcast register inside your activity:

```
// This is a field member of your activity
private BroadcastReceiver tickReceiver;

            // This is inside onCreate method of your activity
            tickReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
            {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
                {
                    if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0)
                    {
                        // Call the widget to update clock time
                        updateTimeInTextView();
                    }
                }
            };
            //Register the broadcast receiver to receive TIME_TICK
            registerReceiver(tickReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
```

And in order to show the current time in am/pm format use:

```
private void updateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        String currentTime = format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        yourTextView.setText(currentTime);

    }
```

hope this helps